# C# copy values from array to list

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, lis

I have following code:

```
for (int c = 0; c < date_old.Length; c++) 
{
    for (int d = 0; d < date_new.Length; d++)
    {
        newList[c] = data_old[c];

        if (date_old[c] == date_new[d])
        {
            newList[c] = data_new[d];
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have four arrays: `date_new`, `date_old`, `data_new`, `data_old` and a List called `newList`.
date_old and data_old have the same length and date_new and data_new too.
I want to loop through the date arrays check if there are equal date values. While I'm doing this, I want to copy every value from the data_old array to newList. When a value is equal, I want to copy the value at this point from the data_new position into the List. 
Here I get a `OutOfBoundException` after the second for loop. What is wrong?

Comment: depends on the size of newList

Comment: How about 'newList = data_old.Distinct().ToArray()'

Answer (score 2):

This exception is thrown when you try to read/write to an array with an index greater than `array.Length -1`.

Double-check the size of `newList`.

Comment: but Lists have variable size or am I wrong? So when I copy values from an array into a List I don't have to declare the size. I have var newList = new List<Double>();

Comment: can you paste the initialization of your list?

Comment: List<T> is variable in length, but you still have to explicitly change the length by adding elements to it.

Comment: try to make an array instead... YourType[] newList = new Yourtype[data_new.Length]()

Comment: No it doesn't - he copies the values multiple times because of the two loops

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `newList` is instantiated as

```
var newList = new DateTime[Math.Max(date_old.Length, date_new.Length)];
```

Also make sure the length of `date_old` equals the length of `data_old`, same thing for `date_new` and `data_new`.

Move `newList[c] = data_old[c];` to the outer for loop if you can (i.e. to line 3), it's gonna overwrite your new data assigned to `newList`.

Comment: ok I've noticed that he copies too much values into the array even when I move the line. I just want him to copy every value once.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int c = 0; c < date_old.Length; c++)
{
     for (int d = 0; d < date_new.Length; d++)
     {
         newList.Add((date_old[c] == date_new[d] ? data_new[d] : data_old[c]));

     }
}
```

with your list solution and this logic you provided